# Trying to install libraries in pypy

Tags: python, pypy

I knew that pypy is faster than CPython so I wanted to try it and it is actually way faster than CPython, however when I install libraries it shows the following:

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\telegram\python -work some-> pip install pillow
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\dell\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site- 
packages (8.3.0)
```

but when I try to import the module (**pillow**):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/telegram/python -work some-/studying code 2.py", line 1, in 
 <module>
import pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

**it is not there!** please help!

Comment: `python39`, emmm, seems you need to use `import PIL` instead of `import pillow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pillow` is an up-to-date fork of the now deprecated Python Image Library (`PIL`). you need to `import PIL` or `from PIL import ...` to use it.
Check out their [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to learn more!

Answer (score 1):

You must run `pip` with the version of Python you want to install the package for.  In this case, you need `pypy3 -m pip install pillow` or something similar---run it with the same interpreter as the script you'll run next.  In your pasted output, we see `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\dell\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages` which is the path for CPython 3.9, not PyPy.

Comment: Ohhh.. so that's why , I also thought that the message is from CPython not from pypy, can you please tell me where shall write (pypy3 -m pip install pillow) exactly? because I tried it in VS code and got this:

PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\telegram\python -work some-> pypy3 -m pip install pillow
pypy3 : The term 'pypy3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I don't know VS code.  You must make sure you run the same version of Python the two times.  However you start Python (or PyPy) to execute `studying code 2.py`, you must run the same Python.

Comment: Thank you , I figured it out ,Thanks again for your time <3